# How do I import an overlappingly namespaced Python package?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, importerror

I have a Python package installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages` called `com.example.dependency`.

I am trying to build a package `com.example.mypackage` with setuptools, that uses the build dependency.

```
├── setup.py
└── com
    ├── __init__.py
    └── example
        ├── __init__.py
        └── mypackage
            ├── __init__.py
            └── // some code
```

```
# inside setup.py I have:
from com.example.dependency import something
```

When I import `com.example.dependency` in the same directory as setup.py I get an ImportError, no such module, when I run it in a different directory it imports fine.

I can solve this problem with a symlink, but as this takes place in an automated build system it is perhaps not the best solution as the minor version of python will change later.

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/. You have a single Python package (`com`) split between two directories (`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/com` and `./com`).

Comment: Are you sure the `com` package in `dist-packages` is a namespace package? Does it have an `__init__.py` module? How does your own `com/__init__.py` look like?

Comment: The plot thickens! `com` is a namespace package, so we can remove the com/__init__.py without implication; but `example` contains functions that we can import, so needs the com/example/__init__.py  

```python
from com.example import something
```

The problem is that it is not looking in the full python path! But rather is stopping locally when it finds `example` but not `mypackage`

Comment: @grahamoptibrium Exactly. Depending on the order listed in `sys.path` the first `com.example` package found will be the one that is importable, and the other one is not importable.

Comment: @grahamoptibrium Maybe have a look at [_PyPA_'s guide "Packaging namespace packages"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). And then look at the content of the `com/example/__init__.py` of the project installed in `dist-packages`, see if there is way to augment this package with your own code.